# SIGABRT after tapped an ImageView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sigabrt

im trying to change the image that generate the func viewDidLoad when i tapped the screen  an imageview, but after tapped the screen i get a SIGABRT in the line

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

here is the code

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        /*application.registerUserNotificationSettings(
        UIUserNotificationSettings(
                forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil))*/

        return true
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
        let alert = UIAlertView()
        alert.title = "Alert"
        alert.message = notification.alertBody
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("Dismiss")

        alert.show()
    }

}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var imageview: UIImageView!


    @IBAction func localNotification(sender: UIButton) {
        let localNotification = UILocalNotification()
        localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5)
        localNotification.alertBody = "Esta es una notificacion"
        localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
        localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let imageUrlString = "http://www.personal.psu.edu/cmr5496/sky_main.jpg";
        let url = NSURL(string:imageUrlString);
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
        imageview.image = UIImage(data: data!);


        let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:Selector("imageTapped:"))
        singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
        imageview.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap);
        imageview.userInteractionEnabled = true;
            }

    func transformar(str: String) -> UIImage {

        let url = NSURL(string:str);
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
        let image = UIImage (data:data!);
        return image!;
    }

    func imageTaped(gestureRecognizers: UIGestureRecognizer) {

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {


    self.imageview.image = self.transformar("http://www.brandontreb.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/screenshot_021.png");
    //imageview.alpha = 0.0f;
    //imageview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeTop;

    })

}
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do and what is the error you are getting ]

Comment: Use the Breakpoint Navigator to set a breakpoint on exceptions.  That should stop your program at the place where the error is encountered.  If you still need help at that point, post the stack trace.

Comment: im trying to change the image after tapped the screen, im getting a SIGABRT but im not getting something more to post here

Comment: here is the project if someone want to see it https://mega.nz/#!oJB0QIiA!mYEk1dlUJkmPnxrRDXKRBq61GIC7bY3E_KESO5r0CLs

Comment: Hi, i m not proficient in swift. But the image loading function need to be in an async task with an observer on a end of load notification. Or else, you will sure have a nil image. For testing, use a local image and see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your project.

Typo: "imageTapped" and "imageTaped" are not the same thing.  The key clue was in the console error message: **-[TestBeaconsSwift.ViewController imageTapped:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b76bc30**

Comment: that was the problem, how were you able to see the console / error message ? when the app crashed, the only thing i could notice was a red indicator for the whole code from my appdelegate.swift file. Im new to the IOS develoment and im using xcode 7 beta to deploy directly to the phone. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

I would assume, its because you haven't unwrapped the data, because the data could be nil.

```
let url = NSURL(string:str)
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
imageview.image = UIImage(data: data!)
```

Replace with

```
if let url = NSURL(string:str) {
    if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
         return UIImage (data:data)
    }else{
        print("image data invalid")
    }
}else{
    print("URL invalid")
}
return UIImage()
```

Comment: i did it but nothings changed

Comment: so data and url are valid and it still crashes?